# How to limit each Jenkins build instance to a maximum of x nodes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to limit a job's build instance to run on up to x number of nodes?

For example, let's say I have 20 slaves and a parent job called "ParentJob". "ParentJob" is configured to run 20 child jobs concurrently, called "ChildJob", on any available slave. Since I need to kick off multiple ParentJobs, I want to limit the child jobs to 5 nodes per ParentJob build instance.

Basically, I want to kick off ParentJob #1, #2, and #3 concurrently, but I don't want all the ChildJobs spawned from ParentJob #1 to hog all the slaves. ChildJobs from ParentJob #1 should use nodes 1-5, ChildJobs from ParentJob #2 should use nodes 6-10, and ChildJobs from ParentJob #3 should use nodes 11-15.

I've looked at Throttle Concurrent Builds plugin and the Lockable Resource plugin, but they don't seem to address what I want to accomplish. They seem to work at the job level only, and not at the build level.

My other option is to write Groovy code to grab x available nodes, label them uniquely, and run the child jobs on these nodes. When the job is finished, I can clear the labels so they're available for the other builds.

Is there a simpler option or plugin that can do this? Maybe I'm over complicating this.

Hope that wasn't too confusing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the jobs you're triggering are not the same job? those are different jobs? if it's the same job Throttle Concurrent Builds plugin is exactly what you need. I might have misunderstood the architecture.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my problem. I've updated the description above, hopefully that is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't find anything, I wrote the following Groovy script for my pipeline job.

This script will grab the first 3 slaves without a "TESTING_.*" label and append a new label. The jobs are then executed on those nodes only, without taking up all the slaves in my farm. Once the jobs are finished, the labels are removed.

```groovy
node ("master") {
    def new_label = "TESTING_" + org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils.random(7, true, true)
    echo "New label for slaves: " + new_label

    try {
        stage('Reserve slaves') {
            reserve_slaves(3, new_label)
        }

        stage('Smoke tests') {
            // Do your parallel jobs here
            // Pass in new_label to the job
        }
    }

    finally {
        stage('Return slaves') {
            remove_label_from_slaves(new_label)
        }
    }
}


def reserve_slaves(number_of_slaves, new_label) {
    def label_prefix = "TESTING_"
    def slaves_with_new_label = 0

    while (slaves_with_new_label < number_of_slaves) {
        for (slave in jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.slaves) {
            def current_labels = slave.getLabelString()

            if (!current_labels.contains(label_prefix)) {
                echo "Adding label '${new_label}' to " + slave.name + ". Existing labels are: ${current_labels}"
                slave.setLabelString(current_labels + " " + new_label)
                slaves_with_new_label += 1
            }

            if (slaves_with_new_label >= number_of_slaves) {
                break
            }
        }

        if (slaves_with_new_label < number_of_slaves) {
            echo "Waiting for nodes to become available..."
            sleep(10) // in seconds
        }
    }
}


def remove_label_from_slaves(label) {
    for (slave in jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.slaves) {
        def current_labels = slave.getLabelString()

        if (current_labels.contains(label)) {
            echo "Removing label '${label}' from " + slave.name + ". Existing labels are: ${current_labels}"

            current_labels = current_labels.replace(label, '')
            slave.setLabelString(current_labels)
        }
    }
}
```